# Sum of associations count by single sql query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

There are two models:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

I've got an array with some category ids. Is there a way to get total items count that belong to categories from my array with single SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** let's get the items in the categories you want from the array:

```
Item.joins(:categories).where(categories: {id: category_ids})
```

**Then** lets get the count for each category

```
Item.joins(:categories).where(categories: {id: category_ids}).uniq.count
```

Comment: Association named categories_items was not found. I have little modified your solution to joins just categories. In result i get hash with count of each category so i can sum it. Is it the best solution? thx

Comment: No I'll add some tweaks to it